# How to do binary collation using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, collation

I have a SQL query like this:

```
select * 
from Customer 
where Upper(CustomerName) Like '%'+ Upper("google") + '%' collate Latin1_General_100_Bin2
```

How can I convert that query into Linq to Entities?

Comment: You can't change collation in Linq AFAIK.

Comment: The conversion to `Upper` defeats the purpose of the collation. What are you trying to achieve?